# How can I transfer white comfrey from the front garden to the back garden by seed?

Tags: germination, perennials

I have successful white comfrey in the front garden with hundreds of flowers.  Presumably the flowers contain the seeds.   Can I grow new white comfrey in the back garden by planting large numbers of fallen flowers?  I wait for them to fall rather than picking them.  I also find on the ground little "brown envelopes", which appear to contain seeds,   see sixth picture here http://wildflowerfinder.org.uk/Flowers/C/Comfrey(White)/Comfrey(White).htm

Presumably I should plant these as well.

Comment: No, sorry. The brown things are dried petals. The seeds will form at the base of the flowers (flowers = white petals + the green bits at the base!). Please see my answer at your other question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to wait for the plant to form seeds to have it growing elsewhere; if the plant you have in the front is large enough, you can split/divide it and replant a section in the back garden. You don't say where you are, but this sort of division is usually done in autumn or in early spring. If you live somewhere that's warm all the time, or has hot summers, just ensure you keep the newly planted section well watered for a few weeks till it settles in.

You can either dig the whole plant up, split and replant one section in the original site, backfilling  around it with soil, or if the patch is large enough, loosen the soil round one side of it, then cut through the middle and lift the half you want to transplant, again backfilling the gap you've left with soil. Both plants, once replanted, will need watering in well. More instructions on precisely how to do it here  http://www.allotment-garden.org/comfrey/how-propagate-comfrey/